# Getting "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable EmailMessage object" when sending mass email with django

Tags: django-views

I tried to send a mass email with django but keeps getting this error: "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable EmailMultiAlternatives object" when I used EmailMultiAlternatives for the admin emial but the error is similar when i swith the admin emil to EmailMessage as I get this error: "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable EmailMessage object"

#### Below is the admin email part:

```
  html_string = render_to_string('form_preview.html', context)
            response = HttpResponse(content_type= 'application/pdf')
            html = HTML(string=html_string)
            buffer = io.BytesIO()
            html.write_pdf(target=buffer)
            pdf = buffer.getvalue()

            admin_mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                subject=f"XXXX|{first_name}",
                body=f"{first_name} just applied for {proposed_course}. Find attached below the details of their application",
                from_email="muhamu@gmail.com",
                to=('mmumdam@gmail.com',),
            )
```

#### Below is the second email:

```
            photograph = request.FILES["photograph"]
            certificate = request.FILES["certificate"]
            resume = request.FILES["resume"]
            id_file = request.FILES["id_file"]

            files = [photograph, certificate, resume, id_file]
            
            admin_files_mail = EmailMessage(
                subject= f"{first_name}'s Files",
                body= f"Please find attached below the documents uploaded by {first_name}",
                from_email= "muhamu@gmail.com",
                to= ['mmumdam@gmail.com',]
            )
            for file in files:
                admin_files_mail.attach(file.name, file.read(), file.content_type)
```

#### And the final part:

```
 subject = "The XXXX|Apllication Submitted!"
            html_content = get_template('applicant_email.html').render({"name": first_name, "title": title})
            from_email = 'muhamum@gmail.com'
            to = ['mmumdam@gmail.com', 'codingresources@gmail.com']

            applicant_msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, to)
            applicant_msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            send_mass_mail((admin_email, applicant_email, admin_files_mail), fail_silently=True)
```